# Extract and link a 64bit gnu c++ lib from a 64bit mscv++ lib

Tags: c++, linker, dllimport

I have built SpiderMonkey on Windows. They provide MSVC++ toolchain and I couldn't build it for mingw. I've built it for 64bit.

It is a DLL, I need to convert its lib to gnu C++ format (.lib to .a).
After looking on the web, I've found here how to do this, roughly:

```
gendef mozjs-45.dll
dlltool --as-flags=--64 -m i386:x86-64 -k --output-lib mozjs-45.a --input-def mozjs-45.def
```

I use TDM-GCC-64 under Code::Blocks. At link time it throws errors like:

```
undefined reference to `__imp__Z13JS_GetPrivateP8JSObject'
```

I have checked the lib content using:

```
nm libmozjs-45.a > libmozjs-45.nm
```

I see there are the same entries as in the def file exported, but that looks different than linker expects (I presume):

```
?JS_GetPrivate@@YAPEAXPEAVJSObject@@@Z
```

**Edit 1**

I have managed to build SpiderMonkey with mingw-w64. Now, at linking time I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `__imp__ZN17JSAutoCompartmentC1EP9JSContextP8JSObject'
```

Looking with `nm` at the lib, I have:

```
d000536.o:
0000000000000000 i .idata$4
0000000000000000 i .idata$5
0000000000000000 i .idata$6
0000000000000000 i .idata$7
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 I __imp__ZN17JSAutoCompartmentC1EP9JSContextP8JSObjectON7mozilla6detail19GuardObjectNotifierE
                 U _head_mozjs_45_dll
0000000000000000 T _ZN17JSAutoCompartmentC1EP9JSContextP8JSObjectON7mozilla6detail19GuardObjectNotifierE
```

Indeed, the definition of the class is:

```
class MOZ_RAII JS_PUBLIC_API(JSAutoCompartment)
{
    JSContext* cx_;
    JSCompartment* oldCompartment_;
  public:
    JSAutoCompartment(JSContext* cx, JSObject* target
                      MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_PARAM);
    JSAutoCompartment(JSContext* cx, JSScript* target
                      MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_PARAM);
    ~JSAutoCompartment();

    MOZ_DECL_USE_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER
};
```

Why the same compiler exports this as `__imp__ZN17JSAutoCompartmentC1EP9JSContextP8JSObjectON7mozilla6detail19GuardObjectNotifierE`, but, when referencing it, expects it as `__imp__ZN17JSAutoCompartmentC1EP9JSContextP8JSObject`?

**Answer**: missed a symbol definition that exclude `MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_PARAM` from build.

Comment: Your tools may work for a C library but not C++. GCC and MSVC++ use
different name-mangling protocols for C++. The same C++ identifier
has a different mangled name in object code generated by each compiler so interlinkage is simply not possible. You'll have to build a C++ library with
GCC to link it with other GCC C++ code.

Comment: @Mike Kinghan Right, so, add it as answer.